# Extra blank line in array-fed ListBox

Tags: excel, vba

Here's what drives it:

```
 Dim wb As Workbook
 Dim arrList()
 Dim iInstances As Long

 iInstances = 0

 For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
  If wb.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then
   iInstances = iInstances + 1
   ReDim Preserve arrList(iInstances)
   arrList(iInstances) = wb.Name
  End If
 Next

 With Sheets(1)
  .Shapes("ListBox1").Height = 136.5
  .ListBox1.List = arrList
 End With
```

Problem:  the code inserts a blank line (which I don't want) at the top of the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
  If wb.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then
      ReDim Preserve arrList(iInstances)       
      arrList(iInstances) = wb.Name
      iInstances = iInstances + 1      
  End If
```

And put the following at the tob of your module.

```
Option Base 0
```

Comment: Thank you for replying but it didn't work.  Yellow line on the debug for arrList(iInstances) = wb.Name; I put the Option Base 0 at the top of the module and everything.  Subscript out of range. Did you test it?

Comment: Yes try it again now I have edited my post - sorry about that, after I tested I noticed I needed to also move the ReDim line.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating an array with an empty 0 index, so you just need to increment your counter *after* adding the workbook:

```
For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
   If wb.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then
    ReDim Preserve arrList(iInstances)
    arrList(iInstances) = wb.Name
    iInstances = iInstances + 1
   End If
Next
```

Comment: Hi Tim, I see you posted the same solution at the same time I was editing.  I didn't steal your code! :)  +1 for also correct code.

Comment: Tim, thanks for responding. I didn't even see this answer; I was busy responding to Reafidy. Thank you both. One of the things I don't like about the board is an expectancy to choose bests, because there are often equally good answers. (But the other was the only answer I saw; I guess it can be decided by the Option Base 0 :-)

Comment: @MM - as long as you got your problem resolved...  Option Base 0 is the default behaviour though: if you don't specify a different Base then zero is always used.